# Web service getting value using LINQ from queue table in SQL database

Tags: c#, beginner, linq, asp.net, web-services

As a test of my C# skills, I have been asked to create a simple web service which will take a message from a queue table in a SQL database and send it to a web application when a button is pressed on the application.  I have never written a web service before so I am going in a little blind here so was after some advise on whether I had done this correct or not.

The stored procedure `usp_dequeueTestProject` gets a value from the top of the list in a table and then deletes the row in that table.  At the moment I do not have this being archived anywhere, would it be better practice to instead of delete this, to just mark it as sent instead?

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetDataLINQ()
    {
        try
        {
            TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext dc = new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext();
            var command = dc.usp_dequeueTestProject();
            string value = command.Select(c => c.Command).SingleOrDefault();
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I've opted for using LINQ for starters, I am not sure if this is the best way to do it or not?  I am only passing through the one string as well... In reality I guess you would normally want to send more than one field, such as datetime sent, message type etc, but wasn't sure what data type to use for this? I have seen this done using a Strut, but wasn't sure if this was correct?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the nature of this "skills test"? Seems like asking the internet for a better solution won't be a good indicator of *your* skills.

Comment: Just to see if I'm able to do a web service really.. I want to impress though so don't want to muck it up by doing something glaringly obvious.

Comment: I mean who is administering the test? A potential employer, a teacher, yourself? If it's an employer who wants to know if you know how to properly write a web service, then getting help from the internet isn't really an indicator of your skillset.

Comment: It's a work project where a number of us have been asked to produce this simple web service. My boss knows I have very limited experience with web services so she will be expecting me to get help.  I am more after some feedback on the code I have written and if it's the correct way to go about it, rather than someone giving me a solution which is better. Some quick suggestions on the questions I have asked would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A Linq-to-SQL `DataContext` is an `IDisposable`, your code isn't calling its `Dispose()` method. Wrap it in a `using` block to ensure proper disposal.
- I would use `var` in the `TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext` instantiation as well, but that's just personal preference. I find `Foo bar = new Foo()` redundant.
- Using `SingleOrDefault` *assumes* that the SP is returning only 1 record. That very well be the case *now*, but the SP being outside of the code, I wouldn't make that assumption. Use `FirstOrDefault` to grab only the first record - this way the day the SP is modified to return more than 1 row, your code won't break.

Something like this:

```
string result;

using (var dc = new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext())
{
    var command = dc.usp_dequeueTestProject();
    result = command.Select(c => c.Command).FirstOrDefault();
}

return result;
```

---

I agree with @Jesse's comment about exceptions usage: the calling code has no way of easily telling a valid response from an error message (exception type, message and stack trace), since your code returns a `string` in every case.

**Let it blow up!**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Should I wrap all my linq code in using so that it properly disposes of the code after use?  Thank you for your comment about the FirstOrDefault as well I will change this in my code.  Could you advise whether a strut would be best to do a web service which returns multiple fields? I am going to look at pulling through more fields as I imagine this is what we will be doing in a future project.

Comment: You mean a `struct`? I'd use a `class` instead, a POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) - a simple class that merely exposes auto-properties should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ is a good choice. You're querying something, so it lends itself to the task.

That being said, the exception handling is atrocious. Making your return values `null`, some command's value from the database or some big honkin' exception text is abusing the `string` data type. I'd remove the `try..catch` altogether and let your client app handle the exception if it knows what to do. In the best case, your `catch` could log the error somewhere then re-throw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I will take out the try catch as you say.  Can you advise what you think I should use if I transfer more than just a string over the webservice? I've done it with a strut, but I wasn't sure if that was the most elegant way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to transfer? Use any data type you like and it will be serialized as you expect.